# Codeigniter: How can i Call an external controller in a controller located in controllers folder

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, controller

I am working with codeigniter in php and my question is that How can i Call an external controller in a controller located in controllers folder.

```
    //this file is Controller2.php in controllers folder
class Controller2 extends CI_Controller
{
function one()
   {
      // Some code goes here..
   }
}


//and now this file is Controller1.php which is also in controllers folder


class Controller1 extends CI_Controller
{
   function one()
   {
      // I want to load Controller2 here
   }
}
```

Please instruct me as i've wasted so much time during googling.

Thanks in advance..

Kamran

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034479/codeigniter-call-controller-from-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, or rather you shouldn't. Any functionality that you need to use in two different controllers should be moved to a library or helper file.

Comment: ..thank you for responding quickly .. or if i want to move required controllers' methods to models then does it make sense?

Comment: Sure, it could. In the strict MVC model than Models are used for mapping (modelling) your data to a format useable by the controller - in practical terms that normally means the Model is where your database interaction / processing lives. In reality Codeigniter is pretty lenient on these things, so I end up with a fair bit of non-database logic in my models because I'm lazy like that. tl;dr yes you can move it to a model if thats easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but not with the default functionality, to use something similar you should use [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) extension for CodeIgniter: [Link](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/)

There are plenty examples and a good thread about the extension.