# call another controller function from controller function in codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter, controller

In codeigniter call another controller method from controller in code igniter

```html
class ManualTrackingUpdate extends MY_Controller 
{
    
    ##constructor Define method
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model("TrackingUpdateInApp_model","MTUD");
      
    }  

public function UpdateDetails(){
        
     
   
       // call model 
      $Insert_details = $this->MTUD->InsertTrackingDetails($columns);
      
      // call here another controller method

    }
    
    }
```

how can do this with codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Call Controller From Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034479/codeigniter-call-controller-from-controller)

Comment: Maybe you should be looking into HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 0):

```
class ManualTrackingUpdate extends MY_Controller 
{

    ##constructor Define method
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model("TrackingUpdateInApp_model","MTUD");  
    }  

    public function UpdateDetails()
    {
         // call model 
         $Insert_details = $this->MTUD->InsertTrackingDetails($columns);

         include('User.php'); 
         $user =  new User();
         $user->abc();
    }
}
```

Comment: [for more example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

Comment: i don't know its modularity wise right or not, but it works for me.

Comment: if it's working for you then close your question by accepting answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this stuff will work for you. not sure but just try it.

constructor.

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/controllername');
```

and now call the function using

```
$this->controllername->functioname();
```

Comment: getting Unable to load the requested class: TrackingUpdation
i am using HMVC